# Enable PivotalTracker estimation for bugs and chores

Tags: pivotal-tracker

The [PivotalTracker Help Center](http://www.pivotaltracker.com/help/articles/planning_with_velocity/) states that:

> You can enable estimation for bugs and chores in Project Settings

How is this enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the box:

> Project > Project Edit Settings > Experimental: Bugs and Chores May Be
>   Given Points [X]